# Oracle Query with AND and OR

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write the following scenario as query in Oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE col1 = 'SOMENAME' WITH (EITHER COL2 = 'Y' OR COL3 = 'Y')
```

Comment: `"SOMENAME"` is invalid. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers (e.g. column names). So it should be `'SOMENAME'` and `'Y'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, old habit of java developers. Have edited my question with better syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `AND`:

```
Select * 
from table1 
where col1 = 'SOMENAME'
 AND (COL2 = 'Y' OR COL3 = 'Y')
```